# Converting UIImage animation to use Cocos2d sprite animation

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimage, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I have an app that uses UIImage animation, and the timing of the animation is inconsistent.  I would like to convert over to using sprite animation with cocos2d.

Can I add this functionality to my existing project?  Are there any good tutorials on how to add Cocos2d to an existing project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen people just use Cocos2D inside an EAGLView with good results. [This fellow](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/16692) seems to have got it working. Having said that, I would probably try to optimize your UIImage animation. Using PNGs is generally faster, and try to scale your animation image frames to the exact display size. And, make sure your animation frame rate isn't above 30 or so.

Comment: Thanks.  My issue with the UIImage animation is trying to time the stopping of the animation.  Currently I use "[self performSelector:@selector(stopAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];".. but if there are any delays due to hardware lag, etc... the animation is cut off too soon.  I can't think of a way to fix that..?

Comment: Ah I see. I would look into using a CAKeyframeAnimation actually. You can put an array of images into the values property and hook up a completion listener. Well, you would have to do a little more than that (namely, setup timing), but that's the gist of it.